# What is the cost of calling a member function of a class through a temporary object if the class doesn't have any member variables?

Tags: c++, templates, perfect-forwarding

I was recently studying the source code of the ENTT library, and I came across something similar to the following snippet of code (note that I have greatly simplified things to make my question brief):

```cpp
// Note that this class doesn't contain any member variables
class TextureLoader
{
public:

   TextureLoader() = default;
   ~TextureLoader() = default;

   std::shared_ptr<Texture> loadResource(const std::string& textureFilePath) const;
};

template<typename TResource, typename TResourceLoader, typename... Args>
std::shared_ptr<TResource> loadResource(Args&&... args)
{
   // Note how a temporary TResourceLoader is created to invoke its loadResource member function
   return TResourceLoader{}.loadResource(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

int main()
{
   std::string texFilePath = "tex.png";
   std::shared_ptr<Texture> myTexture = loadResource<Texture, TextureLoader>(texFilePath);
   return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the `loadResource` function template is capable of loading any resource type (e.g. `Texture`, `Shader`, `Model`, `Sound`, etc.). The documentation of the library states that a loader class should ideally not contain any member variables. I imagine this is because every time `loadResource` is called, a temporary of the loader class passed to it is created to invoke its `loadResource` member function. And that's where my question lies: what is the cost of `TResourceLoader{}.loadResource()`? Is the compiler able to remove the creation of the temporary because it doesn't contain any member variables? Is there a better way to this?

Comment: Yeah, I think whoever downvoted got a bit trigger-happy. However, code in this question is certainly not Minimal. This business of shaders and such is not really important for the question, is it?

Comment: @SergeyA You are right, but I felt that if I didn't provide some extra background someone would ask "Why don't you make the loadResource member function static?" I can only justify my motivation by showing how the class is used.

Comment: @SergeyA See the following classes for more information. I think the source code of ENTT is really fantastic, which is why I'm always trying to learn from it! https://github.com/skypjack/entt/tree/master/src/entt/resource

Comment: Hahaha I though that when Sergey asked about the "wonderful machine" he was referring to ENTT.

Comment: The negative vote and subsequent close vote is the presence of  "Is there a better way to this?"  By asking that the question becomes too broad or opinion based.  While this may be a worthy question, many people here feel that certain phrases should always be flagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no significant performance implications, although code will be penalized ever so slightly. In order to understand the implications better, let's try to decompose the code into something which would be similar to compiler's generated code:

From:

```
return TResourceLoader{}.loadResource(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
```

To:

```
char Storage[1]; // Any object in C++ is at least 1 byte, including classes with no members
Storage(&Storage); // Pseudo-code illustrating calling constructor
loadResource(&Storage, <args>); // considering loadResource can't be inlined
Storage.~Storage();
```

In code above, compiler will see that both constructor and destructor are default, and since class has no member are, indeed, trivial - so those could be safely omitted.

What you end up with is a necessity to allocate 1 byte in automatic storage, which on modern architectures usually means decrementing stack pointer register, following by incrementing it.

This is incredibly fast operation, but it still not instantaneous.

Comment: That "1 byte allocation" operation will extremely likely be optimized out by the compiler.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo it can't unless the function was inlined. API requires an object there.

Comment: in this case everything is done as part of the body of `loadResource`, and `TResourceLoader` does not escape the function boundaries. Why would the compiler ever generate code to allocate one byte, to immediately throw it away afterwards? Isn't the optimization local to the body of the function? Why would it need inlining?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo since `TextureLoader::loadResource` is not visible to compiler, compiler needs to fully follow ABI. Assuming AMD64 ABI, a pointer to the class object is also passed to the function. Compiler needs to have this pointer, and for this it needs the object allocated somewhere!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the compiler will optimize out the creation of a temporary variable without any data members. There basically is no codegen required for that. You can verify it yourself and play with various optimization levels on an online tool like [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org).